# How to get complete list of records in List view

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

How do i get the complete list of records in a list view. I know using getRecords() we can get but its only limited to maximum of 20 records. But i need list of complete records for the List view. Is it possible?.

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
        List<Bug__c> lChanges = new List<Bug__c>();
        public GenerateCardListView_Cntrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
            setCon = controller;
            lChanges = setCon.getRecords();            
            system.debug('&&&&&'+setCon.getRecords());
            system.debug('&&&&&'+setCon.getRecords().size());
        }
```

The size in the debug returns 20 if the size is more than 20.

Answer (score 8):

The [StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) works a bit like a database cursor, you need to ask for records a page at a time. The key methods are **getHasNext()** and **next()**. Using these around each call to the **getRecords()** method until you've moved through the entire record set. This simple controller demonstrates this...

```
public with sharing class DemoStandardSetController 
{
    public List<Test__c> AllRecords {get;set;}

    public DemoStandardSetController(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController)
    {
        stdSetController.addFields(new List<String> { 'Name' });

        AllRecords = new List<Test__c>();

        while(stdSetController.getHasNext())
        {
            for(Test__c testRecord : (List<Test__c>) stdSetController.getRecords())
            {
                AllRecords.add(testRecord);
            }
            stdSetController.next();
        }
    }
}
```

My demo page looks like this...

```
<apex:page standardController="Test__c" extensions="DemoStandardSetController" recordSetVar="fred">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AllRecords}" var="Record">
            <apex:column value="{!Record.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that with your code, the records in last page won't be gotten. When we arrive in the last page, the  `getHasNext()` returns `false` and we don't go to the while.

Answer (score 6):

Use `getResultSize()` method of the StandardSetController. The `getRecords()` returns only the list of objects in the current page set. And this is [set by default](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_pagination.htm) to 20 records.

[Here is the documentation.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_getResultSize.htm) And here are [all methods of the StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_instance_methods.htm).

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
        List<Bug__c> lChanges = new List<Bug__c>();
        public GenerateCardListView_Cntrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
            setCon = controller;
            lChanges = setCon.getRecords();       

            // Here is the output of the set size
            system.debug('&&&&&'+ setCon.getResultSize());    

            system.debug('&&&&&'+setCon.getRecords());
            system.debug('&&&&&'+setCon.getRecords().size());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the last values you should repeat the line in the while still one time.

```
 while(stdSetController.getHasNext())
 {
        for(Test__c testRecord : (List<Test__c>) stdSetController.getRecords())
        {
            AllRecords.add(testRecord);
        }
        stdSetController.next();
 }
 for(Test__c testRecord : (List<Test__c>) stdSetController.getRecords())
 {
        AllRecords.add(testRecord);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `setPageSize(integer)` for `StandardSetController`,

e.g.

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
        List<Bug__c> lChanges = new List<Bug__c>();
        public GenerateCardListView_Cntrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
            setCon = controller;
            **setCon.setPageSize(100);**
            lChanges = setCon.getRecords();            
            system.debug('&&&&&'+setCon.getRecords());
            system.debug('&&&&&'+setCon.getRecords().size());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getRecords()` only returns the records **displayed** in the page.

If you want getRecords() to return all the records in the view option query, **trick your APEX code to temporarily display all records**, then  reset your controller set to display the initial number of records.

This approach is faster and more performant than using nested for/while loops.

e.g.

```
   ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

    List<Bug__c> lChanges = new List<Bug__c>();
    public GenerateCardListView_Cntrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
         setCon = controller;
         integer selectedPageSize = setCon.getPageSize();
         setCon.setPageSize(2000);//Trick: increase number of records displayed
         lChanges = setCon.getRecords(); //if they are less than 2000, all records should be returned
         setCon.setPageSize(selectedPageSize);//Display initial number of records
     }
```