# Lightning: Get list view records

Tags: apex, list-view, standardsetcontroller, bug, platform-bug

How can one get **ALL** the records from a list view in a visualforce page running in Lightning? (Since no checkbox for selecting are available)

[Similar old question.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18717/how-to-get-complete-list-of-records-in-list-view#answer-18733)

With an adaptation from that question's answer, I have:

```
public SomeClass(ApexPages.StandardSetController con) {
    if (con.getSelected().size() > 0)
        lots = [SELECT Name FROM Custom__c WHERE Id IN :con.getSelected()];
    else {
        Transient Set<sObject> sObjects = new Set<sObject>();
        sObjects.addAll(con.getRecords());
        while (con.getHasNext()) {
            con.next();
            sObjects.addAll(con.getRecords());
        }
        lots = [SELECT Name FROM Custom__c WHERE Id IN :sObjects];
    }
}
```

And this works fine in Salesforce Classic, for each condition. But in lightning it works differently each time, looks like every time I test this, it chooses a different list to get the records. (Looks like a SF bug)

Comment: Any luck here? Anything you would like for me to change about my answer to be more helpful?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson I'm just waiting to see if this question gets any official attention before accepting your answer, because basically there is nothing else we can do at this moment to get the list view records in lightning

Comment: Makes sense. Perhaps someone more clever than I can figure out how to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a shot in the dark, but try calling `setFilterId` on your `StandardSetController` to get more deterministic behavior.

```
public static final String DESIRED_LISTVIEW_LABEL = 'All';
public SomeClass(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    if (!controller.getSelected().isEmpty())
        return [SELECT Name FROM MyObject__c WHERE Id IN :controller.getSelected()];
    for (SelectOption listViewOption : controller.getListViewOptions())
    {
        if (listViewOption.getLabel() == DESIRED_LISTVIEW_LABEL)
        {
            controller.setFilterId(listViewOption.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

You can also expose the available filters ( `List<SelectOption>`) returned from `getListViewOptions()` as a property on your controller and **let the end user decide which list view they want**.

<s>**Update**</s> Lightning [does not support Javascript buttons](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112052/related-list-button-not-displaying-on-opportunity-record-in-lightning-experience).

You do not need to add an extra user input step. Instead of making `DESIRED_LISTVIEW_LABEL` final, you can get it through page parameters if you make your list button `Execute Javascript` as follows:

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict"
    var fcf, index, payload, search = window.location.search,
        params = search.substring(1, search.length).split('&');
    for (i in params) {
        payload = params[i].split('=');
        if (payload[0] == 'fcf') {
            fcf = payload[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    w.open('/apex/MyPage?ListView=' + fcf);
})(window);
```

You could simplify the above somewhat since `fcf` seems to be the only parameter most of the time, but I tried to make it robust against future changes in the url. Then you can do:

```
public static final String LISTVIEW_PARAM = 'ListView';
public Id desiredFilterId
{
    get
    {
        return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(LISTVIEW_PARAM);
    }
}
public SomeClass(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    if (!controller.getSelected().isEmpty())
        return [SELECT Name FROM MyObject__c WHERE Id IN :controller.getSelected()];
    if (String.isNotBlank(desiredFilterId))
        controller.setFilterId(desiredFilterId);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, I was trying to test your workaround but couldn't from the apex class (no problem from execute anonymous), I ran into `sObject type 'ListView' is not supported.` problem. I read your response at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64004/list-view-visibility#answer-66796 but I didn't understand the solution

Comment: @Jose For some reason I thought `SOQL` would work. Anyway, I updated it with a better code sample that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this works perfectly as a workaround (with an extra step for the end user), but the question/bug remains in place, why the `StandardSetController` isn't getting the list ID in context?

Comment: @Jose I think the issue is just that *there is no context Id*. The defaulting behavior in classic seems to match what you expect, whereas the defaulting behavior in Lightning seems more arbitrary. It shouldn't be necessary to add a step for the end user, though. At least not as I understand it.

Comment: I didn't elaborate in the use case, but the extra step is necessary since I need to work with the records in the selected list view (dynamically). I'm just curious what is people doing to get the records from the list view in lightning. (Other than making the user select again the list)

Comment: @Jose How are you passing data to this page? Perhaps you can pass in `DESIRED_LISTVIEW_LABEL` through page parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36278/discussion-between-jose-and-adrian-larson).