# Related list button not displaying on opportunity record in Lightning Experience

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, related-list

There is an apex button that is not displaying when the record is viewed in Lightning Experience. The related

In Salesforce Classic it is working fine , When I move to Lightning, it is not displaying.

Related list is a custom object which is executing javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript custom buttons are not supported in Lightning. Read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme), it says:

> Custom buttons that use a JavaScript content source aren’t supported in Lightning Experience. You can replace some of the functions covered by these buttons by using point-and-click tools, like Process Builder, Visual Workflow, or code-driven approaches.

Comment: Can you add a supporting documentation link? This answer is very short and likely to get flagged for deletion.